# Call a SalesForce API from .NET Core Web API and deserialize the response in to a c# object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, salesforce, asp.net-web-api2

I am new to sales force. from my .Net Core Web API I am trying to call my sales force API.

By using below code :

```
 string new_Contact_url = "some URL";
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new_Contact_url);
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer 00D0E00000019dU!AQUAQK7Mcfutr7Y03dsuuKy9wyMt.GzRCUve6Rll8tDr2APzuHE.J2UjXXYt1vNPiQB5Fn2BCvoC7PwEwN9OLuyTbvTAp8Dj");
                request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                var resp = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resp);
                //inplace of object I want to convert this into List<AccountDetail>
                //List<AccountDetail>
```

by using the Curl command in command prompt i get this response as a json

```
{
  "eTag" : "355105a",
  "info" : {
    "cloneable" : true,
    "createable" : true,
    "deletable" : true,
    "displayColumns" : [ {
      "fieldApiName" : "Name",
      "label" : "Account Name",
      "sortable" : true
    }, {
      "fieldApiName" : "Parent.Name",
      "label" : "Parent Account",
      "sortable" : true
    }, {
      "fieldApiName" : "Type",
      "label" : "Type",
      "sortable" : true
    }, {
      "fieldApiName" : "Owner.FirstName",
      "label" : "Owner First Name",
      "sortable" : true
    }, {
      "fieldApiName" : "Owner.LastName",
      "label" : "Owner Last Name",
      "sortable" : true
    } ],
    "eTag" : "7e8d2",
    "filterLogicString" : null,
    "filteredByInfo" : [ {
      "fieldApiName" : "CreatedDate",
      "label" : "Created Date",
      "operandLabels" : [ "6-6-2018" ],
      "operator" : "GreaterThan"
    } ],
    "label" : "All Accounts",
    "listReference" : {
      "id" : "00B0N000004w1WaUAI",
      "listViewApiName" : "AllAccounts",
      "objectApiName" : "Account",
      "type" : "listView"
    },
    "orderedByInfo" : [ {
      "fieldApiName" : "Name",
      "isAscending" : true,
      "label" : "Account Name"
    } ],
    "updateable" : true,
    "userPreferences" : {
      "columnWidths" : {
        "Type" : -1,
        "Parent.Name" : -1,
        "Owner.FirstName" : -1,
        "Owner.LastName" : -1,
        "Name" : -1
      },
      "columnWrap" : {
        "Type" : false,
        "Parent.Name" : false,
        "Owner.FirstName" : false,
        "Owner.LastName" : false,
        "Name" : false
      }
    },
    "visibility" : "Public",
    "visibilityEditable" : true
  },
  "records" : {
    "count" : 2,
    "currentPageToken" : "0",
    "currentPageUrl" : "/Account/AllAccounts?pageSize=2&pageToken=0",
    "listInfoETag" : "7e6aa798",
    "nextPageToken" : "2",
    "nextPageUrl" : "/Account/AllAccounts?pageSize=2&pageToken=2",
    "previousPageToken" : null,
    "previousPageUrl" : null,
    "records" : [ {
      "apiName" : "Account",
      "childRelationships" : { },
      "eTag" : "e6aa7986b72",
      "fields" : {
        "CreatedDate" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : "2018-06-08T10:49:31.000Z"
        },
        "Id" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : "0010E00000M2f7aQAB"
        },
        "LastModifiedDate" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : "2018-06-25T09:05:08.000Z"
        },
        "Name" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : "-- UNKNOWN --"
        },
        "Owner" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : {
            "apiName" : "User",
            "childRelationships" : { },
            "eTag" : "4686ddfd6281",
            "fields" : {
              "FirstName" : {
                "displayValue" : null,
                "value" : "System"
              },
              "Id" : {
                "displayValue" : null,
                "value" : "0050N000007jHIuQAM"
              },
              "LastName" : {
                "displayValue" : null,
                "value" : "API User"
              }
            },
            "id" : "0050N000007jHIuQAM",
            "recordTypeInfo" : null
          }
        },
        "OwnerId" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : "0050N000007jHIuQAM"
        },
        "Parent" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : null
        },
        "ParentId" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : null
        },
        "SystemModstamp" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : "2018-06-25T09:05:08.000Z"
        },
        "Type" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : null
        }
      },
      "id" : "0010E00000M2f7aQAB",
      "recordTypeInfo" : null
    }, {
      "apiName" : "Account",
      "childRelationships" : { },
      "eTag" : "815b8ac88",
      "fields" : {
        "CreatedDate" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : "2018-06-08T10:48:00.000Z"
        },
        "Id" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : "0010"
        },
        "LastModifiedDate" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : "2018-06-25T09:04:33.000Z"
        },
        "Name" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : "AAA Transportation"
        },
        "Owner" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : {
            "apiName" : "User",
            "childRelationships" : { },
            "eTag" : "4686ddfd62818d54f92a08bd73726606",
            "fields" : {
              "FirstName" : {
                "displayValue" : null,
                "value" : "System"
              },
              "Id" : {
                "displayValue" : null,
                "value" : "0050N000007jHIuQAM"
              },
              "LastName" : {
                "displayValue" : null,
                "value" : "API User"
              }
            },
            "id" : "0050N000007jHIuQAM",
            "recordTypeInfo" : null
          }
        },
        "OwnerId" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : "0050N000007jHIuQAM"
        },
        "Parent" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : null
        },
        "ParentId" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : null
        },
        "SystemModstamp" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : "2018-06-25T09:04:33.000Z"
        },
        "Type" : {
          "displayValue" : null,
          "value" : null
        }
      },
      "id" : "0010E000",
      "recordTypeInfo" : null
    } ]
  }
}
```

What I understood from this response is there is lot of meta data information in this . **The Important part that I wish to get out from response is the records tag**

I created the Equivalent C# class from record tag

```
public class AccountDetail
    {

        public string Etag { get; set; }
        public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ApiName { get; set; }

        public List<OwnerDetails> Owners { get; set; }
    }

    public class OwnerDetails
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string ApiName { get; set; }

    }
```

So How Do I extract information from records tag into a equivalent List of C# object.this line 
 var obj = (List)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resp);

Comment: You need to make sure you're matching the types correctly. For example: `Owners` is an object in the request body but you have it as type `List<T>`. Also, have you looked  into using `[JsonProperty()]` attribute on your properties to help map them to your class appropriately? Try using this [website to generate your c# classes from json](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: what records tag do you need ? (inbold). Sorry, I didn't understand

Comment: @MarkC. Can you post an example for this I have not used JSONProperty before. Also It was my understanding that Owners is a nested object so I created a separate class for it and referenced it as a List<Owner> in Account details.

Comment: @Prany In the big JSON I have pasted there is a function Pointer records: inside which there is a property records: I need to extract this value and fill it into a c# object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Newtonsoft.Json

```
var files = JObject.Parse(YourJSON);
var recList = files.SelectTokens("$..records..records").ToList();
foreach (JObject obj in recList.Children())
 {
   foreach (JProperty prop in obj.Children())
      {
        var key = prop.Name.ToString();
        var value = prop.Value.ToString();
         //Do your stuffs here
      }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks Prany this was exactly what I needed to extract the values.

Answer (score 0):

[JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) can help you to achieve what you need. Just implement converter for your class with all required rules of filling properties of your object and use it on deserialization like:

```
List<AccountDetail> accountDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AccountDetail>>(json, new ListOfAccountDetailsJsonConverter(typeof(List<AccountDetail>)));
```